# What will be selected by execution expression in Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, aspect

What will this expression select in aspect oriented programming - `("execution(* *.*(..))")`? Will this select all the methods irrespective of their scopes, return type or parameters?

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is a sloppy, low-quality question, I think you are seeking advice here which helps you avoid to look into an AspectJ tutorial for even five minutes. I suggest you do that, it should answer your question. The question is off-topic here. SO is about solving programming problems, not about answering general questions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation. - [Check this!](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-aop/writing-spring-aop-aspectj-pointcut-expressions-with-examples/)

As you see in the link above you can match methods with specific return types, parameters and/or scopes.
For example (if you are not eager to open this link):

> Matching all **public** methods in EmployeeManager

```
execution(public * EmployeeManager.*(..))
```

> Matching all public methods in EmployeeManager **with return type** EmployeeDTO

```
execution(public EmployeeDTO EmployeeManager.*(..))
```

> Matching all public methods in EmployeeManager **with return type** EmployeeDTO and first parameter as EmployeeDTO

```
execution(public EmployeeDTO EmployeeManager.*(EmployeeDTO, ..))
```

Answer (score 0):

("execution(* *.*(..))") all method are selected